# Java Super and Sub in same file

Tags: java, inheritance

Is it considered bad form to include a subclass in the same .java file as the superclass? Any inherent advantages or disadvantages of this as opposed to separating them into their own files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823238/writing-classes-in-single-file-or-multiple-files

Comment: Its ok for testing/practice purposes, but in production keeping in mind modularity, readability etc it is recommended to have each class in their own files.

Answer (score 4):

**Is it considered bad form to include a subclass in the same .java file as the superclass?**

Having the sub class in same .java file that contains a super class is not considered as bad but not recommended. But this opinion varies from person to person so everyone has own opinion.

**Any inherent advantages or disadvantages of this as opposed to separating them into their own files?**

You know that a single .java file can have only one public class. As from [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)

> This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per
>   compilation unit. This restriction makes it easy for a Java compiler
>   to find a named class within a package. In practice, many programmers
>   choose to put each class or interface type in its own compilation
>   unit, whether or not it is public or is referred to by code in other
>   compilation units.

so yes definitely, it can effect the inheritance if you want the sub class to be public as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage or disadvantage as such.

The main reason behind putting different classes in separate .java files is code organization and maintainability. It is always considered a good practice to put irrelevant classes separately.

For example imagine a scenario when you have a large set of Class and you want to search a particular Class it would be much easier if that Class is written in a separate file rather than incorporating it with other Classes in a same file.

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect

Comment: @Vogel612 We can't say that just by putting a class in a separate file is advantageous or not, it depends on the scenario, according to the conventions and industry standard it is considered a good practice to write different classes in different files.

Comment: That is incorrect. Having multiple classes in one file has inherent disadvantages, and inherent advantages. These are only applicable when considering use-case, but as the advantages and disadvantages are the same, the use-case is irrelevant.